# Constraint with slice and map union: invalid operation: cannot index c (variable of type T constrained by sliceOrMap)

Tags: go, generics

In the type parameter proposal [Composite types in constraints](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/HEAD/design/43651-type-parameters.md#composite-types-in-constraints), I see the following code:

```
// sliceOrMap is a type constraint for a slice or a map.
type sliceOrMap interface {
  []int | map[int]int
}

// Entry returns the i'th entry in a slice or the value of a map
// at key i. This is valid as the result of the operator is always int.
func Entry[T sliceOrMap](c T, i int) int {
 // This is either a slice index operation or a map key lookup.
 // Either way, the index and result types are type int.
 return c[i]
}
```

The proposal suggests that this code is valid, however it doesn't actually compile. The compiler error is:

> invalid operation: cannot index c (variable of type T constrained by sliceOrMap)

Why does the program not compile?

Comment: the link answers the question. tl;dr if the union includes maps, it must include only maps (with same key and value types) for the index expression to be valid

Comment: yes, you give me the answer ." The specs is not same with the proposal " .

Comment: correct. there's actually several places where the proposal differs from the actual, specified, implementation. in general, it's best to refer to the language's normative reference whenever possible

Comment:  maybe other people have the same question!